# If a miner does not include an uncle block (and thus forgoes a nephew reward), does the uncle miner still get a uncle reward?

Tags: uncle-blocks

From the [Alchemy docs](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-calculate-ethereum-miner-rewards)

> Uncle and nephew block rewards: The final part of our block reward
> calculation is to add additional rewards for mining an Uncle block
> (uncle reward) or including it in the latest block (nephew reward). An
> uncle block occurs when two miners create blocks at almost the same
> time. While both blocks are valid, the network can only accept one
> block at a time. Therefore one block is rejected and labeled as an
> uncle block. Instead of letting this block go stale, a nephew reward
> equal to 1/32 of a block reward is issued to any miner willing to
> later include this uncle block inside a block they are mining.
> Additionally, an uncle reward is issued to the miner of the uncle
> block

Q: Is an uncle reward only awarded if an uncle is included in a block? In other words, if no miners decide to include an uncle (and thus all forgo a nephew reward), no reward is given to the miner of the uncle. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

If a block isn't included in the main chain, nor as an uncle then that block is like it was never mined. The miner won't receive rewards.